# how to make a jest test fail at first time even using jest.retryTimes?

Tags: jestjs, jest-circus

in my Jest test suite,

i use

[jest.retryTimes(4)](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/jest-object#jestretrytimes)

because of the particular and instable architecture of the software. And this works as expected.

There are some test that must to pass at the first time so for these particular test i need to set

```
jest.retryTimes(1)
```

at the beginning of the test, restoring

```
jest.retryTimes(4)
```

at the end.

There are two problems :

1. The problem is this configuration is global, and test are executed
   in parallel, so when this test start, it put 1 to jest retry for all
   the test running at this moment. I would like to make only this
   particular test fail the first time.
2. Jest Circus ignore the update of jest.retryTimes at the beginning and at the end
   of the test, it keep considering 4 temptative before of raise the failure.

I read the documentation but I think I cannot obtain this result.

any suggestion?

Thanks

Comment: Probably in before/afterEach. Did you try it?

Comment: thanks @EstusFlask . not working. i'm setting retryTimes(4) in a script loaded by setupFilesAfterEnv in the jest.config.js , but even setting retryTimes(1) in beforeEach, it keep trying 4 times. it look like retryTimes cannot be overwritten at runtime.

Comment: I didn't check how the feature works yet but it seems raw. For now I'd probably go insetad with custom wrapper for `test` that does a retry like `retryTest`.